# Need help writing a script to re-pair with a Bluetooth Mouse

Tags: keyboard, scripts, mouse, bluetooth

I'm having a bit of trouble with my htpc setup, the bluetooth keyboard connects automatically and works, but the mouse doesn't and has to be re-paired for it to work. It also keeps disconnecting.

I'm using Microsoft Wedge keyboard & mouse with [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Plugable-Bluetooth-Adapter-Raspberry-Compatible/dp/B009ZIILLI) adapter on Ubuntu 15.04.

I was hoping to write a script I could execute using the keyboard to reconnect the mouse. It would require unpairing, discovering and then pairing again with the mouse.